# How can I implement a rest that has both an upload and a a payload in flask-restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I've got the following code for flask-restplus.

The POST request generates a Swagger UI that allows to upload a file.

Then I want the PUT request to also allow for a file to upload from Swagger UI and also provide a payload body.

For this code the Swagger UI is generated with an file browse and upload input field and a json body payload.

[image]

The problem is that the PUT request's api.payload returns None.

If I remove the `@api.expect(upload_parser)`, the api.payload returns the fields defined by `amazon_data_csv_update_model`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
upload_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
upload_parser.add_argument('file', location='files', type=FileStorage, required=True)


amazon_data_csv_update_model = api.model('AmazonDataCSVUpdateModel', {
    'uuid_to_update': fields.String(description='The UUID of the file to update', required=True)
})

@api.route('/amazon-data/upload')
@api.expect(upload_parser)
class AmazonDataCSVUpload(Resource):

    def post(self):
        upload_args = upload_parser.parse_args()
        uploaded_csv_file = upload_args['file']  # This is FileStorage instance
        json_uuid = AmazonHandler.upload_amazon_data_csv(uploaded_csv_file)
        return {'amazon_data_uuid': json_uuid}, 201

    @api.expect(amazon_data_csv_update_model)
    def put(self):
        put_payload = request.json
        print(put_payload)
        put_payload = api.payload
        print(put_payload)
        upload_args = upload_parser.parse_args()
        uploaded_csv_file = upload_args['file']  # This is FileStorage instance
        json_uuid = AmazonHandler.upload_amazon_data_csv(uploaded_csv_file, uuid)
        return {'amazon_data_uuid': json_uuid}, 200
```

Comment: Try with importing  __request__  from flask and access it with request.json in PUT request handler.

Comment: Thanks @KonradSitarz. request.json also returns None.

Comment: @RaamEE how is it. have you manage to get this going?

Comment: I haven't solved this the best of my memory. Since then I moved to using uvicorn and FastAPI, which I find are better implementations than flask and flask-restplus. I

Answer (score 0):

In you code, it was applied two expect to put. In this case, the second expect is ignored even if it is showing on browser.
So you are able to get the value of the first expect.
As far as I know, it is able to apply two expect in a endpoint.